# How to configure a HUD for Omaha game?

Tags: omaha, hud

I donwloaded a HUD for playing Omaha for first time recently.

I guess the default configuration is accurated for Holdem and not for Omaha.

What stats are important in Omaha game?

Comment: I would say that the stats that are important in hold'em are also important in omaha. I don't play much Omaha but I would guess that paying special attention to stats like 3-bet, fold to 3-bet, vpip, c-bet, fold to c-bet, squeeze and fold to squeeze would be good for omaha.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I decided to post how I have configured mine.

[image]

Personally, I think Omaha is different than Texas Holdem, at least at low tables.

I want to know VPIP and how much a player is a caller, because at low tables, they pay with their trash projects.

Also, at Omaha the Flop is more decisive. I consider C-Bet Flop and Call to C-Bet Flop important.

I had in mind Clarko advices, but at low tables squeeze is not so important in my opinion. I play Pot Limit, and limpers use to pay twice.

I only show 3-BET on preflop, to realize if they just raise when they have AAxx, or they do with a broader repertoire.

I may miss something essential, but this is how I presently have it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer varies depending what strategy you are playing.

Here is mine. First is I don't like to become crazy analyzing tons of numbers each hand so it is short. Once I get used to I may add a column.

[image]

I am learning how to play LAG (Loose and Agressive) atacking the blinds from cutoff and button positions and 3-bet prefloping with more than AA-xx to isolate the raiser with positional advantage.

The call and raise Flop C-Bet is to vary the range of flops I C-Bet.

I think the initiative is less important in Omaha unless for the flop (specially for Holdem coming players) so I show general bet and call turn and river streets.

I incorporated the floating calling ratio to practice the float against weak c-bets in an uncaught flop.